# Disable Password Auto Generation by spring after Upgrading the Deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-security

Since `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated, I have updated my `SecurityConfig` class with defining `SecurityFilterChain` as a bean in my config class but none of the config is working and spring still generates Security Password!

Here's my new WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().disable();
      http.authorizeHttpRequests()
              .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
              .requestMatchers("/role1/**").hasAnyRole("admin")
              .requestMatchers("/role2/**").hasAnyRole("admin")
              .requestMatchers("/role3/**").hasAnyRole("admin")
              .anyRequest()
              .permitAll();
     return http.build();
  }
}
```

Spring still generates password:

```
Using generated security password: ******-****-****-****-**********
This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before     running your application in production.
```

I have tried excluding `SecurityAutoConfiguration` class from the main application but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can either remove the `UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration` by doing:
`@SpringBootApplication(excludes = UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class)` or you can provide a `UserDetailsService` of your own:

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that actually helped. Actually I'm using keycloak with oAuth2 to implement access management. Maybe I can implement my own custom UserDetailService with keycloak. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you might want to use Spring Security's OAuth2 Resource Server support https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html. By using that support, the `UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration` will automatically backoff as well.